# Load GLTF model from binary data, not URL

Tags: javascript, reactjs, three.js, gltf, react-three-fiber

I'm using [drei usegltf](https://github.com/pmndrs/drei#usegltf) to load a glTF asset:

```js
export default function GLTFModel(props: GLTFModelProps) {
  const gltf = useGLTF(props.model);
  return <primitive object={gltf.scene} />;
}
```

```js
<Canvas>
 <Suspense fallback={null}>
    <GLTFModel model={glbUrl}/>
 </Suspense>
</Canvas>
```

While this works well for glTF assets available from a local or remote URL, I'm attempting to render a glTF asset I have available as a binary blob

1. API returns GLB as `application/octet-stream`

```
const response = await fetch(apiUrl, {});
const data = await response.blob();
```

2. Want to render the binary data

```
const gltf = useGLTF(data);
```

Is there a way to work this out without API uploading the GLB to a URL?

Comment: Have u got any solution for this? I am also looking for same thing.

Comment: Unfortunately, no @Firu. Currently in need of this again